# ASP NET Session cookie being filtered out by browser on AJAX requests using https

Tags: .net, ajax, session, cookies

I am opening this thread to document an issue I have stumbled upon a few minutes ago. Moreover, I looked everywhere for an answer but got no luck at it, and after a considerable amount of trial and error, I managed to figure out a fix for this. Let me explain:

We have a NET6 website whose controllers get hit by client-side ajax requests from within the same site.
Furthermore, everything works just fine when running the site on Localhost, however, when publishing to Azure, we started getting 401-unauthorized errors for all AJAX requests.
After doing some research, I noticed the browser was filtering-out the ASP.NET session cookie, thus, the endpoints failed to authenticate.

**SOLUTION:**
Initially, we were setting the AJAX request's url as "/Controller/Action", which failed to authenticate. The solution was to replace the url above with *location.protocol + '//' + location.host + "/Controller/Action/";* and it worked like a charm.

Hit controller's action using AJAX and https with .NET session cookie.